# Splitting a string every multiple delimiters

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to split a string every seven pipelines `|`. I have a string like this one and I want that every seven goes in a new line.

```
*wood*|*tree*|*animals*|*vegatables*|*house*|*plane*|*bus*|.........|
```

I know that if I want to split by the delimiter `|` I should do:

```
pwd | cut -b2- | tr '|' '\n'
```

But every seven of them in a new line I don't know how to do that. The output that I want to get is this:

```
*wood*|*tree*|*animals*|*vegatables*|*house*|*plane*|*bus*|
*dog*|*tiger*|*shark*|*ant*|*apple*|*banana*|*egg*|
....
```

So how can I do that?. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you include sample input with expected output?

Comment: Using gnu sed: `sed -E 's/([^|]*\|){7}/&\n/g' <<< '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l'`

Comment: also update your question with a) sample data that's more than 14 strings long and b) the expected results; from the current wording I can't tell if you want to display just the 7th/14th/21st items, or you want to display the entire output but with a carriage return embedded after every 7th item, or ... ?

Comment: `tr '|' '\n' <<< '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l' | paste -d '|' - - - - - - -`

Comment: @zoit: Did my suggested `sed` command work for you?

Comment: `sed 's/[|]/&\n/7;P;D'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering my string is `1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|`
Here is what I tried (reading the string from standard input):

```
printf  "$(sed -E 's/([^|]*\|){7}/&\\n/g' <<< '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|')"
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|
8|9|10|11|12|13|14|
15|16|17|18|19|20|21|
22|
```